# linear algebra linear equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra

Are the following two systems of linear equation equivalent:

$$\begin{cases}a + b = 1\\b = 2\\b = 3\end{cases}$$

---

$$\begin{cases}a + b = 1\\2a + 2b = 2 \\a = 2\\a=3\end{cases}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Also, for some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Can you help me,please?

Comment: What does an equivalence between two systems of equations mean?

Comment: Or more importantly, now that I've actually looked at your systems, how can $b=2$ and $b=3$?  And how can $a=2$ and $a=3$?  Do do know that $2\ne 3$?

Comment: also i cant understand but question is exactly like this..

Comment: @soldiermoon:  We need you to be the expert about what you want to ask.  If you don't know what you are asking, who will?

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent : 
$$\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  \begin{cases}a + b = 1\\b = 2\\b = 3\end{cases} & \iff 2 = 1 \\
                                                  & \iff \pi = e \\
                                                  & \iff \text{there goes any statement with a false logical value} \\
                                                  & \iff\begin{cases}a + b = 1\\2a + 2b = 2 \\a = 2\\a=3\end{cases}
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}$$